# how to print the result of log in textview?

Tags: android

I want to print the list of currently running application, I am new in android please help. I want to know how to print this log in `textview`.

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) 
getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
 {
   Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " 
   +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: 
  "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
}
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25351846/3505534

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

Take a `LinearLayout` with orientation `vertical` in layout file. find reference of that `layout` and add `textview` to that `layout`.

```
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);

        for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
         {
            TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
            valueTV.setText(recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: 
      "+recentTasks.get(i).id);
            valueTV.setId(i);
            valueTV.setLayoutParams(new   LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not proper way to print log in `TextView`. Just see your logs in console/logcat.

Comment: he want  to print the list of currently running application in a TextView **Read Question again**

Answer (score 0):

**use this way**

```
yourtextview.setText("Application executed : " 
   +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: 
  "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"\n");
```