# How to see large debug message

Tags: android, debugging

I use android Log class for general purpose debugging but now the need is to display large text in the device itself as logcat message are truncated and inconvenient.

I tried to create a popup window with a textview inside but it seems like I cannot place it anywhere I want, if I do it may get WindowLeaked error etc.

I would like to place the debug window anywhere on the ui system such as anywhere in the activity class or Views.

Does android has any built-in debug-ui, something like

Dialog.debug(String message);

Otherwise what hack will require to achieve that?

**EDIT**
This I need not for viewing LogCat log but seeing any random variables in code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.TextView; 

class ReadLogDemo extends Activity { 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        try { 
             Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 
             StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder(); 
             String line = ""; 
             while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { 
                   log.append(line);
              } 
              TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
               tv.setText(log.toString()); 
          } catch (IOException e) { } 
     }
}
```

Courtesy: [log to be viewed in activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863841/can-logcat-results-for-log-i-be-viewed-in-our-activity)

Comment: thanks but i need to print any random string instead of putting them to logcat i need them show in a popup window, something like javascript alert box

Comment: Ok, then use `final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     builder.setMessage(log.toString);   builder.show();
`

Comment: okay i will check AlertDialog works from inside the view classes and let you know.